# What is mongo 4.4 bulk size with transaction?

Tags: c#, mongodb, transactions, bulkinsert

My problem is when I'm inserting ~10k documents in bulkInsert operation with session i receive error

> {"Command insert failed: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.."}

However when i insert ~9,5k or less the same documents everything works fine. My mongo cluster is hosted in AWS cloud.

I have only found information that single BsonDocument max size is 16mb. How can i deal with even larger bulk inserts?

```
var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<BsonDocument>>();  
... some code here..  
var upsertOne = new InsertOneModel<BsonDocument>(bsonDoc);

bulkOps.Add(upsertOne);

return collection.BulkWrite(session, bulkOps);
```

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53464 looks related

Comment: @AlexBlex so if i understand it well i have to wait for mongo 4.4.7(hope so) to get this work without decreasing bulk operation size

Comment: Symptoms look similar. I would wait for 4.4.7 to check if it fixes the problem. It might not. Are you using transactions or only bulk writes?

Comment: Transactions are complex and should be used with care. If you really need to insert 10k documents as a single transaction it smells problems in schema design.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue using `BulkWriteAsync` with a `ReplaceOneModel` (you use `BulkWrite`... I suggest you go async, but that's an aside).

I have a strategy that performed well and deals with a bulk insert of tons of documents. I think my method combined with the method of making smaller batches in the first place might do the trick (ref. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67924224/64348)). The strategy is composed of a few tactics...

**Tactic One: use `IsOrdered`**

Pass a [BulkWriteOptions](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_BulkWriteOptions.htm) to `BulkWriteAsync` with IsOrdered set to `false`. `IsOrdered` allows MongoDB to perform the inserts [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298291/how-to-improve-mongodb-insert-performance). More importantly, it may, in your case, allow the operation to succeed for [many documents](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/BulkWriteOptions.html) (not necessarily all -- see strategy 2).

NOTE: That last link I provided is to the Java documentation which says,

> If true, then when a write fails, return without performing the remaining writes.

The C# documentation [talks](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_BulkWriteOptions_IsOrdered.htm#!) only about the ordering itself. Anyway, this use of `IsOrdered` being false sets up the second strategy.

**Tactic 2: When the bulk insert fails, retry the remainder**

The thing is, a full bulk insert on a large number of documents will likely fail -- but not completely. This is actually ok, because MongoDB gives you a nice out: a list of the documents that couldn't be written (inserted) as part of the [MongoBulkWriteException](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoBulkWriteException_1.htm) that is thrown. Again, my scenario was an upsert, but I'm willing to bet a strict insert will have the same/similar issues.

Using the `WriteErrors` property of this exception, you can get a list of those documents, and retry them.

**Possible Solution**

Here I outline a possible solution. I'm not going to provide the entire set of code because I can't and because I have some other strategies in play such as retries with [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff#:%7E:text=Exponential%20backoff%20is%20an%20algorithm%20that%20uses%20feedback,in%20order%20to%20gradually%20find%20an%20acceptable%20rate.) and [jitter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/exponential-backoff-and-jitter/), it's part of a generic repository implementation, I deal with various other errors, and so on -- things that may or may not be relevant to this answer.

So, pseudocode using documents of type `T`:

```
// setup models; here's mine; yours will be `InsertOneModel`
var models = toUpdate
    .Select(x => new ReplaceOneModel<T>(new ExpressionFilterDefinition<T>(doc => doc.Id == x.Id), x) { IsUpsert = true })
    .ToArray();
```

Then make a retry loop and handle the needful exception, which exposes a `WriteErrors` property of type `IReadOnlyList<BulkWriteError>`. There's a bit of assumptions you'll have to make about my code; in the error handler, I have to match up the error to the original model so I can ensure I have the right ones. If you don't get the idea, I can try to add more context.

```
for (var i = 0; ; i++)
{
    try
    {
        await collection.BulkWriteAsync(models, new BulkWriteOptions { IsOrdered = false });
        return result;
    }
    catch (MongoBulkWriteException<T> bwe)
    {
        if (i > DelayCount) return something;

        // rebuild the collection of models, using the failed ones; EntityModel
        // basically contains the entity, and the error category (you may not
        // want to retry all of them depending on the category)
        var myModels = bwe.WriteErrors.Select(x => new EntityModel<T> { Entity = models[x.Index].Replacement, ErrorCategory = (RepoErrorCategory)x.Category }).ToArray();
        models = handlerResult.Replacements
            .Select(x => new ReplaceOneModel<T>(new ExpressionFilterDefinition<T>(doc => doc.Id == x.Id), x) { IsUpsert = upsert })
            .ToArray();
         
        // maybe do an optional delay here...
    }
}
```

The key to matching up the errors to the models is using the `Index` property of the `WriteError` in the list of errors to lookup the original entity (document) you are trying to save.

At this point, after as few iterations as possible, everything should be inserted and the size and time limits have been circumvented.

Essentially, on each pass, you are winnowing down the remaining work each time to just the failed documents. Ideally, that's fewer each time.

**Final Advice**

I suggest straying away from making this transactional if you can. These tactics probably won't work correctly in that scenario. For example, it seems rather obvious that a transactional insert of 10000 documents won't be able to make use of `WriteErrors`. I'd be willing to bet that 10000 documents *in most cases* are unrelated, and their inserts can be independent.

Avoiding the transaction will allow you to skirt the limits much more easily.

Comment: Wow thanks for explanation i check your tips in a days and let u know

Comment: @Wojna did this help? Perhaps I can add some more thoughts...

Comment: It helped me with better understanding transaction problem. To fully fix that issue i have to wait for new version of mongodb to solve it. Thank you for great answear, it will help many people.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an extension method like the following in order to break up your extremely large `bulkOps` list to batches of whatever size you want and execute `BulkWrite` a couple of times in order to get around the limits. if each batch tends to take close to 60 seconds, you may have to create a new transaction in each loop iteration below in order to avoid hitting the 60 second time restriction for mongodb transactions.

```cs
foreach (var batch in bulkOps.ToBatches(5000))
{
    collection.BulkWrite(session, batch);
}
```

here's the extension method i usually use:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Extension method for processing collections in batches with streaming (yield return)
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the objects inside the source collection</typeparam>
/// <param name="collection">The source collection</param>
/// <param name="batchSize">The size of each batch</param>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ToBatches<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int batchSize = 100)
{
    var batch = new List<T>(batchSize);

    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        batch.Add(item);
        if (batch.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return batch;
            batch.Clear();
        }
    }
    if (batch.Count > 0)
        yield return batch;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work your code slices my bulkOps but in the last loop iteration(the moment that i exceed that limit) throws WriteConflictError. The only workaround i found is to turn off transaction or bulk insert smaller BsonDocs/less bulkOps

Comment: @Wojna sorry about the typo. approved your edit.

Comment: I still wounder what is the limit? It's the max bytes waiting to save to db? My single BsonDocs are 100% sure less than 16mb?

Comment: @Wojna afaik mongo transaction have 2 limitations. first is the 16mb oplog message limit. the other one is the 60 seconds time limit. does the error occur around the 1 minute mark of starting the transaction? if so, you will have to close the transaction and start a new one in each iteration of the above mentioned foreach loop.

Comment: @Wojna have a look at this article: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-transactions-and-read--write-concerns